# How to create a custom intent and calling helper intent using Actionsdk?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

Please find my action.json file content

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "testapp"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "talk to Developer"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "BUY",
      "intent": {
        "name": "com.example.sekai.BUY",
        "parameters": [{
          "name": "color",
          "type": "SchemaOrg_Color"
        }],
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "find some $SchemaOrg_Color:color sneakers",
            "buy some blue suede shoes",
            "get running shoes"
          ]
        }
        },
        "fulfillment": {
          "conversationName": "testapp"
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "testapp": {
      "name": "testapp",
      "url": "https://us-central1-samplejs2-id.cloudfunctions.net/testApp",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2,
      "inDialogIntents": [
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Please find my index.js file content

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin     = require('firebase-admin');
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = actionssdk({debug: true});

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
app.intent('com.example.sekai.BUY', (conv, input) => {
  console.log("Inside custom intent");
    conv.ask('<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
   ' The color you typed is' +
   `<say-as >${input}</say-as>.</speak>`);
 });
 app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv, input) => {
    conv.ask('<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
    'You are entering into samplejs application by typing ' +
     `<say-as >${input}</say-as>.</speak>`);
});
app.intent('actions.intent.CANCEL', (conv) => {
    conv.close(`Okay, let's try this again later.`);
  });
app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
    if (input === 'bye') {
    return conv.close('Goodbye!');
  }
   conv.ask('<speak>You said, ' +
    `<say-as >${input}</say-as>.</speak>`);
});
//exports.app  = app;
console.log("global----------->",global);
 exports.testApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Whenever I call the custom intent "BUY" using any color, instead of calling my custom intent it is calling "intent.Text". How to fix this issue?

While creating cloud function I have select JavaScript option.

For creating a custom intent, is these much updates is need in action.json?
Is there any option for creating custom intent?

How to call this helper content in the js file?

```
app.intent('ask_for_place', (conv) => {

     conv.ask(new Place(options));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom intents are only triggered as welcome intents for "deep linking". Once the conversation has started, all conversational intents will be reported as `TEXT`.

So for the intent `com.example.sekai.BUY` you defined in your actions.json file, and if your Action was named something like "super store", then the following invocation would trigger that intent:

> Hey Google, ask super store to find some blue sneakers

but once the conversation had started, asking "find some blue sneakers" would trigger a `TEXT` intent.

The Actions SDK with actions.json is primarily intended for use by systems that provide the natural language processing and just want to get the text after it has been converted from speech.

If you want more sophisticated natural language processing, where each phrase in the conversation will trigger a user-defined Intent, take a look at Dialogflow.

Comment: how to use or call the intent      "app.intent('ask_for_place', (conv) => {

     conv.ask(new Place(options));"         in js

Comment: These are two different questions you were asking - go ahead and ask another StackOverflow question to address this one.